# writing my own code to import users

Tags: user, database, batch, user-registration

I need to batch create lots of users and I have their emails and some profile details like phone number and address. This data is in a google sheet.  I just need to generate usernames and set initial passwords for them before sending login credentials to their email. Security is not a concern. How can I do this programmatically?

1. Can I use phpmyadmin to directly insert rows into the `#__users` and the `#__user_usergroup_map` tables? The password in the table is hashed, I have no idea how hard it would be to hash a password string and insert it into the table. Besides, what should I do with the `id` column? Can I just find the largest id number and then simply `++` for each user to be imported?
2. Does Joomla have a class or function that offers this simple utility like `JUser::addNewUser($username, $password, $email)` so that I can just write some simple code to retrieve data from google sheet and feed it into a helper function like above?

Comment: This post may be enough for you to write your own solution:https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22148/creating-users-programmatically-causing-conflict-with-logged-in-username-display